# child shell does not use the variable exported by parent shell

Tags: bash, shell

i create three shells

p1

```
#!/bin/bash
TVAR=ISP1; export TVAR
p2.sh
```

p2

```
#!/bin/bash
TVAR=ISP2
p3.sh
```

p3

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $TVAR
```

p3 print `ISP2`, but `TVAR` is not exported in p2, why does p3 use the variables of P2?

i see *A child shell will inherit the environment of the parent shell.The environment will contain what is exported by the parent shell.* in `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427946/bash-script-is-not-inheriting-its-parents-env`

Comment: TVAR is in the environment of p2. Since you did not remove this variable from the environment in p2, it is logically also contained in the environment of p3 (or any direct or indirect child process which p3 creates). In this way your question is not even related to bash. You would get the same effect in any process which puts something into the environment.

Comment: @user1934428  hi, I'm actually migrating my script from sh to bash, and in the sh environment p3 prints ISP1 :(

Comment: Sure it does, and I explained that this is the expected behaviour. Why don't remove you the variable from the environment, if you don't want to have it?

Comment: @user1934428   yes, TVAR in p2 needs to be removed, this is bad code

Comment: So, what is your question? How to remove something from the environment? If this is the problem, please update your post to express this explicitly, because this is not clear from the way you worded your question.

Comment: @user1934428   sorry I may not have made it clear, I saw in that link that the child shell will use the variables exported by the parent shell, which is true when tested in the sh environment, but in bash the variables in p2 are not exported but are used by p3, this is My problem, now I think it's the difference between the two, so I need to modify the script

Comment: "To export" means "to place into the environment", so once you put the variable into the environment in p1, it is kept there for all children and grand children, until there is some process down that chain, which on purpose removes it from the environment.

Answer (score 1):

The `export` is inherited, but the value of the exported variable is not protected in any way. If `p2` changes its value, then its changed in `p2` and all its children.

In some more detail, `export` simply says "put this variable where other processes can see it"; it's a property of the variable's name, not of its value.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I am running in the sh environment, p3 prints ISP1, and bash becomes ISP2, which may be the difference between bash and sh